# Permission denied for standalone.sh" : error=13

Tags: ubuntu, sh, wildfly

I am trying to build a web application with jboss-wildfly 10 application server - maven - jpa - java but I get this error code:

```
Error running 'UniPortal': Cannot run program "/home/mert/dev/WF HR/bin/standalone.sh" (in directory "/home/mert/dev/WF HR/bin"): error=13, Permission denied
```

I am using Ubuntu/Gnome 16.04.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: can you run the command along with sudo

Comment: no, how can I do that? i just click the run button on intelliJ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need to make standalone.sh executable. Try running this in a terminal:

```
$ chmod a+x "/home/mert/dev/WF HR/bin/standalone.sh"
```

This will make the file executable by all.